# HIVE MSCK ERROR - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask (state=\ 08S01,code=1)

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am ingesting data from one cluster to another and I am using beeline to run MSCK file from 1st cluster.
MSCK was working until feb 27 and after that I have started getting below error messages.

```
NFO  : Executing command: MSCK REPAIR TABLE cubcus_display
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask (state=\
08S01,code=1)
```

I have tried : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/running-command-hive-table-results-running-msck-error-error-while-processing-statement-failed-error
But i did not work. How can we solve this?

- Beeline version: 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292
- Hive Version: 3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152

Comment: check hdfs permission and the user who is running msck command.